# Grab all text between starting string delimiter and ending character delimiter

Tags: linux, sed

I am hoping to parse a file in Linux. Basically, each time the pattern `[protein=proteinA]` occurs, I want to maintain `proteinA`. In other words, I hope to retain all characters between the nine characters:

```
 [protein=
```

and the one character:

```
]
```

I hope to do this for each pattern in the file, which would lead to an output that looks like:

```
proteinA
proteinB
proteinC
proteinD
```

What is a simple command to achieve this in Linux?

Answer (score 0):

A simple `sed` solution is

```
 sed 's/\[protein=\(.*\)]/\1/'
```

If every line in your input looks like `[protein=something]`,
then the above command should work fine. 
If you have any other kind of data, and you don’t like the results
that you get from the above, then you’ll need to specify what you do want.

Answer (score 0):

A general solution where tags may have any text is to use the following sed command:

```
sed -i.bak 's/\[[^=]*=\([^]]*\)]/\1/g' <file to process>
```

This command will work on `[tagname=something]`, and will remove `[tagname=`, and `]`, where tagname is anything, not just `protein`.

`-i.bak` will process your file and put original file to a filename with `.bak` extension.

Answer (score 0):

you can just `grep` out the data you 
want:

```
$ grep -oP '\[protein=\K((?!]).)+(?=])' file
```